# Duplicate Category URL Title - Problem

Tags: categories

Using EE v2.9.0. and Latest MSM

I created a new category group and created a category called miscellaneous.

I already have a seperate category group with a category called miscellaneous.

This caused a web page to stop pulling through entries when the category in the url was 'miscellaneous'.

As soon as i changed the category_url_title to something else the entries on the web page started to pull through once again.

I searched online and someone said it was a bug? But also said it should be been fixed in v2.4.0 or there abouts.

I saw a post from someone with an even newer version to me claiming they had the same problem.

Does anyone have a fix or a solution other than chaning url_title?

Cheers,

Wes.

Answer (score 0):

I think url_title needs to be unique, otherwise how is EE going to know which category to show? I don't really see a way around that requirement.

Comment: surely EE should generate a miscellaneous1 like it does in channel:entries then, as opposed to it letting you create a category with the same url_title. I just figured because it was under a different group and the group is assigned to only one channel that it would work.

Comment: I think it _should_, but in this case, too, the url_title would be different. You'll just have to do it manually for now.

Answer (score 0):

Use category_id instead of category_url_title to pull entries. The category url title can be changed manually from category edit page.